# Error with tensorboard on Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have recently installed tensorflow, and it seems working fine until I was trying to display computing graph using tensorboard. I got the following error:

```
python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=/tmp/basic/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.platform
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"d\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

Any suggestion about how to solve the problem?

Comment: Seems similar to the common errors listed in the Tensorflow download and install ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#mac-os-x-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-syntax)).   
Did you try pip upgrading protobuf?

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled the older version of protobuf on my mac, and reinstalled tensorflow, and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a TensorBoard bug rather than a usage issue. Could you file a bug against it on our [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new)?

It will be way easier for us to track it down if you can give us a clean repro, including:
- How you installed TensorFlow
- The events file that triggers this bug

The issue you're encountering is related to the latest code from `master`; most people install from pip, but I've been seeing a few issues where people's pip installations are somehow sucking in new code from master. Are you intending to use cutting-edge unreleased source from our master branch, or did you install e.g. version 0.7.1 and are surprised that you have unstable code?